# Display list items equally indented

Tags: css

I'm using this CSS code

```
#main ul li {
  list-style-type: disc;       
  list-style-position: inside; 
}
```

for displaying list items.

The problem is that if the list items spreads over more lines, new lines aren't indented. My list renders the text below the dot and I'd like it rendered indented.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Don't use this:

```
list-style-position: inside;
```

Use this:

```
list-style-position: outside;
```

To compare, see: http://jsfiddle.net/HKPUr/

Comment: It was outside before. I had to declare it `inside` because it was too to the left (not in the same level as other text).

Comment: Then you need a different way to solve *that* problem. You have to keep the `list-style-position` set to `outside`. I'll help you with this if you can show some code where it's (as you said) `"too to the left"`. If you use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show me your code, make sure you untick "Normalized CSS".

Comment: @bpeterson76 Thank you I used them and helped.

Comment: @thirtydot Thank you outside + margin + padding helped. btw. that means the phrase "untick "Normalized CSS""?

Comment: @bpeterson76: Well, what do you know? He just needed to be reminded about margins and padding? :)

Comment: @xralf: I meant that if you were going to use [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) to show me your broken code, that you should [untick this box](http://i.stack.imgur.com/x3F3a.png), because it's confusing when dealing with margin/padding problems.